# Does tetrachromacy affect eye color?

Tags: neurophysiology, vision, human-eye, color

The majority of people have three cones in their eyes, though there are rare cases of some people having 4 cones (tetrachromacy). There is some genetic testing to support evidence of tetrachromacy, as well as some less reliable tests, but there have only been a handful of confirmed cases. The amount of cones present in a person's eyes determines the range of colors they can see. Tetrachromacy is associated with mutations of the X chromosome.

Does the X chromosome affect eye color significantly? Do people with tetrachromacy have a higher variation in eye color on top of being able to see a more diverse range of colors?